# How to generate a Log file in my machine when batch file is run as cronjob

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, logging, cron

Im running a Batch file as cronJob in my windows 7 machine,all I wanted is I want to create a log file ,when the cron Job is run along with the data,which it was displaying in the console.
The data ,is the echo statements which are present in the index.php which i have imported in the batch file.
Help me out to solve this issue.
index.php

```
<?php
echo "Welcome" ;

$fileD = "Login_".date('Y-m-d').".csv";
$fp1 = fopen($fileD, 'a+');

//Getting the files from below mentioned folder
$iterator1 = new FilesystemIterator("C:/wamp/www/logs1");
$iterator2 = new FilesystemIterator("C:/wamp/www/logs2");
$filelist = array();
foreach($iterator1 as $GLOBALS['entry1']) 
{
    if (strpos($entry1->getFilename(), "p1") === 0) 
    {
        $filelist[] = $entry1->getFilename();
   echo $entry1;
    }
}
foreach($iterator2 as $GLOBALS['entry2']) {
    if (strpos($entry2->getFilename(), "p2") === 0) {
        $filelist[] = $entry2->getFilename();
    echo "<br>";
echo $entry2;
    }
}


$file1 = file_get_contents($entry1);
fwrite($fp1, $file1);

$file1 = file_get_contents($entry2);
fwrite($fp1, $file1); 
fclose($fp1);
echo "<br/>";
echo "Done";
 echo "<br/>";
 //Deletes log file present in the logs folder
$n1= "$entry1";
if(!unlink($n1))
 {
  echo ("Error deleting file1 $n1");
  }
   else
   {
   echo ("Deleted $n1");
  }
   echo "<br/>";

  $n2= "$entry2";
  if(!unlink($n2))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting file2 $n2");
   }
     else
  {
     echo ("Deleted $n2");
   }

 echo "<br/>";
    foreach (glob("*.csv") as $filename) 
    {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
        echo "<br>";

    }

echo "<br>";

//$insertionDate = substr($filename,6,10);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stat";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$file = file_get_contents($fileD);
$count = preg_match_all("/,Login,/", $file, $matches);



echo "Csv first word ";
$insertionDate = substr($file,1,10);

echo "<br/>";
echo "Total Hits:" . $totalLines = count(file($fileD));
echo "<br/>";
echo "Login:" . $count;


// Insert the Total hits and the corresponding success and failure count
$sql = "INSERT INTO hit_s (HitDate, count, category,success,failure,tcount,ocount)
VALUES ('$insertionDate', $totalLines, 'Hits',$success,$fail,$treeCnt,$oCnt)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Total hits record inserted successfully \n";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}




$iterator = new FilesystemIterator("C:/wamp/www/Fed");
$filelist1 = array();
foreach($iterator as $GLOBALS['entry3']) 
{
    if (strpos($GLOBALS['entry3']->getFilename(), "*.csv") === 0) 
    {
        $filelist1[] = $GLOBALS['entry3']->getFilename();

    }

}
echo $GLOBALS['entry3']; 


echo "<br/>";
$entry3="$fileD";
$n3= "$entry3";
 if(!unlink($n3))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $n3");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $n3");
  }
  echo "<br/>";


$conn->close();


?>
```

In batch file im calling the index.php file like below
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe C:\wamp\www\Fed\csv\index.php

Comment: Post the code that you have please

Comment: Yes, as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [syslog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) will work for you:

```
$access = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Unauthorized client: $access {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} ({$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: Hi @hd1 i will put in index.php file and try,will let you know